# SSRS Report - Dataset Filters

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I've written a report for SSRS and Im using dataset filters with expressions to filter the report info. I seem to either have this expression wrong or the filter is not working correctly:

```
=IIf(Parameters!DoctorID.Value = "All" Or Parameters!DoctorID.Value = "", "*", Parameters!DoctorID.Value)
```

What I want to accomplish with the above code is if DoctorID = ALL or "" (blank) then I want to omit it from the filters so I return information for all doctors.  However, whenever the value of DoctorID = ALL, I'm returning no rows what so ever. It should be the case that i'm getting ALL rows since DoctorID is not a specific number.

Does the "*" (star) not denote an omitting of that filter? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter formula you provide is only half the equation: what is the operator and what are you comparing this to? And yes, I haven't seen SSRS use asterisk as a wildcard.

Consider putting your filter into the query for the dataset. The SQL WHERE clause can get pretty powerful. I would write your filter into the query as

```
  ...
WHERE
   @DoctorID = 'All' OR @DoctorID = ''
   OR @DoctorID = myTable.DoctorID
```

This will also let you move to a multiple value parameter pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually used a variation of your answer to solve my issue. WHERE (@DoctorID = 'All' AND 1 = 1) OR (doctor_id = @DoctorID) seems to do the trick.